# Wanted: Progress bar for login (not startup)

Tags: macos, login

Once I reach the login screen and have entered my password, I wait.
And wait.
The desktop icons appear, the dock appears, the clock appears in the menubar.
*Okay - now I can open...oh, oh, wait...the external drive software wants to load.

Okay, now it's done, I'll just...wait, there's a rainbow cursor.

Alright, now I can...oh, wait, more menubar icons appearing.

(opens large book and...waits)*

I would like to find some measure of a progress bar or something that tracks the login process and lets me know once the system is done.  I know the system never truly sits idle but I mean "ready to be used" without waiting for more things to load, update, install, or anything else that's going to cause a bouncing icon or rainbow cursor.

Aside from CPULED or some other device to see generically if the chip is being used is there any sort of extension or other mechanism that would provide this?

Comment: If the machine's not ready to go, it's also not going to be in any state to accurately sync a 'thermometer' display. You could wait for the flurry of CPU activity to diminish in Activity Monitor. I watch the myriad menu bar add-ons I have… otherwise I just use it as an excuse to go make tea. It's not the wait, it's the waiting for the wait. [This is actually fine on my Mac Pro, but my folks have a spinny rust iMac from about 5 years ago, where you could make good headway on writing a novel, let alone reading one, while you wait]

Comment: The problem is the system is done when the desktop icons appear. The problem is that you startup apps take a long time. I would try removing your login items - and then see which one causes the issue - alternatively why do you need to log out?

Comment: Anything that would be capable of monitoring the login process would itself be another task for the CPU to handle, slowing things down further. I would suggest trying to reduce the number of Login Items and menulets, rather than adding to them.

Comment: Also "External Drive software"??? Get rid of that, for starters.

Comment: @mmmmmm:  I have three partitions - one Catalina, one Mojave for 32-bit apps, one Windows.  Occasionally I change between them.  Occasionally system updates require a restart.  Occasionally the power goes out.

Comment: @benwiggy:  I have two Western Digital external drives and on login it loads the WD Discovery software.

Comment: As I say: get rid of that. You don't (shouldn't) need them for normal drive operation, and they have a reputation for causing problems.